# How to know if the key up event has been already done its job or not in the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a key up event handler for a text box.
In that event handler I am checking for the key code 46/8 (Back space/Delete). And am getting the resulted value of the text box after these keys are pressed.

Lets say my textbox has 1234 and I want to get the value of the the text box in the event handler after deleting the last character. That mean I need 123 but when I read the value of the textbox it still shows 1234. How can I read the value of the text box after the event has done its job?

Comment: How about you share some code so we can see what (potential) issues there are?

Comment: I think that if you use `change` instead of `keyup`, you'll get the changed value.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Onkeyup event is fired when key is up and textbox value already updated. Which browser are you using?

Comment: use `keyup` instead of `keydown` or `keypress`

Comment: What browser do you use? I cannot reproduce on Google Chrome, Ubuntu 13.04. [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EQhgd/)

Comment: We think, you are triggering `keydown` event, not `keyup`.

Comment: Using the `keyup` event as you've described is working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/TWPUz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `keyup` event:

> The keydown, keypress and keyup events fire when the user presses a key.
>
> **keydown**
>   Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keypress** Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keyup**
>   Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

[Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

since you have no related code posted.. i am assuming (with what you have mentioned)

> That mean I need 123 but when I read the value of the textbox it still shows 1234.
>   .. you are using keydown event...

use keyup

```
 $('#inputID').keyup(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have a code like below.

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8) {
        alert($(this).val())
    }
})
```

It will return value after the key is pressed.